# Domain of adjoint of unbounded finite-rank operators

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, adjoint-operators, unbounded-operators

I am studying closed/closable operators and their adjoints and I am confused:
is it true to say that the domain of the adjoint of an unbounded linear functional is necessarily $\{0\}\subset \mathbb{R}$?

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $T\colon D(T)\subset H\to \mathbb{R}$ be a densely defined linear operator.

- If $T$ is unbounded on $H$, then $T^*$  is not densely defined:
  See e.g., Kato's book "Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators" Problem III.5.18

> Every closable operator with finite rank is bounded. (Thus an unbounded linear form is never closable.)

On the other hand,

- For $T$ densely defined, the adjoint operator $T^*$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $H$ is densely defined if and only if $T$ is closable (e.g., Pedersen,  Analysis Now, Theorem 5.1.5.).

But since
$$D(T^*)=\{ r \in \mathbb{R}\mid \forall h\in D(T),\exists g\in H\text{ such that } r(Th)=(g,h)_H \},$$
if $0\neq r_1\in D(T^*)$ then for $r_2$ we have $ r_2(Th)=(\frac{r_2}{r_1}g,h)_H$.
Hence, if there is one non-zero element $r$ in $D(T^*)$, then we have $D(T^*)=\mathbb{R}$, isn't it?

But $D(T^*)=\mathbb{R}$ will imply that $T$ is closable, and because its range is $\mathbb{R}$, it's bounded.

Does it mean that if $T$ is an unbounded linear functional, the domain of its adjoint is necessarily $\{0\}\subset \mathbb{R}$? (Similar argument works for $\mathbb{R}^n$ for the range of $T$)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T:D(T)\to\Bbb K^n$ is unbounded then the domain of $T^*$ will be some subspace that is not dense.

If $n=1$ there are precisely two linear subspaces of $\Bbb K^n$, namely $\{0\}$ and $\Bbb K$. Since $\Bbb K$ is dense this leaves just $\{0\}$. On the other hand if $n\geq2$ there are many more subspaces, and all except $\Bbb K^n$ are not dense. In fact any proper subspace $V\subset \Bbb K^n$ can be realised as the domain of the adjoint of some unbounded operator $T:D(T)\to\Bbb K^n$.

**Example.**  Let $f_1:D\to \Bbb K$ be an unbounded functional and $f_2:H\to \Bbb K$ a bounded functional. Then $(f_1,f_2):D\to \Bbb K^2$, $x\mapsto (f_1(x), f_2(x))$ has
$$\{0\}\times\Bbb K\to H, \qquad (0,y)\mapsto f_2^*(y)$$
as an adjoint, since
$$\langle(f_1,f_2)(x), (0,y)\rangle_{\Bbb K^2} = f_2(x)\cdot y =  \langle x,f_2^*(y)\rangle_H$$
holds for all $(0,y)\in\{0\}\times \Bbb K$.

Comment: Thank you! Is this written somewhere explicitly as a readily quotable statement? >If $T:D(T)\to\Bbb K^n$ is unbounded then the domain of $T^*$ will be some subspace that is not dense.

Comment: It follows from the arguments you have given:  The adjoint has lives on $\Bbb K^n$, the only dense subspace is $\Bbb K^n$ itself. If the domain of the adjoint $T^*$ is dense then $T^{**}$ has dense domain too and $T^*$ is closed, but being closed and having a Banach space as domain and codomain implies that $T^*$ is bounded, which also gives boundedness of $T$.